# Broadcasting Proof of Concept on android

Tags: android, google-play

I am doing an hackaton and I want to broadcast the proof of concept of my android application to the jury. The problem is : I want it super easy to install my application and I don't want to pay 25$ for launching something that will target at most 20 people.

For instance it would be great if we could provide an url, and if someone click on it, it goes to a webpage with a download button and you click on it and it install it on your smartphone. That easy !

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You want an page to download something? Why not doing it? What's the problem with it?

Comment: I didn't knew we could do it. I thought we had to use a store.

Comment: Welcome to Android, where you can distribute your app however you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance it would be great if we could provide an url, and if someone click on it, it goes to a webpage with a download button and you click on it and it install it on your smartphone.

Then do just that. So long as the Web server is set to serve up APK files with the appropriate MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`), and so long as the device is set to allow installation from arbitrary sources (in Settings > Security), this works just fine.